# Android ImageView full screen

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I'v a problem to show an image in fullscreen mode with `ImageView` in .xml file.

I've 4 images for portrait and 4 for landscape and the sizes are:

Landscape:

1. l: 320x200px
2. m: 480x320px
3. h: 840x480px
4. xh: 1280x720px

Portrait:

1. l: 200x320px
2. m: 320x480px
3. h: 480x840px
4. xh: 720x1280px

And the xml file is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
    android:gravity="center" android:background="#fff" android:weightSum="1">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/paginasplash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/screen"                        
/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

But the image never fit the screen size. Also trying different settings such ad `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerInside"` solved the problem.

The best i can get is an image with a little border on top and bottom.

How can show at full screen the images?

There are different dimension that i've to use?

Comment: Try **not** to give `weightSum` to the layout, if you must give it, add `weight` to the child as well(in this case weight=1). Also show a screenshot of the result.

Comment: hi use relative layout first. Inside relative layout use linear layout with vertical orientation.then give android:weigth=1 for four image view.Then give padding for relative overall.

Comment: could you provide an example xml?